# How to increase camera view size

Tags: camera

[image: What the view is currently]

How do i change the camera view to fill up the whole screen in the render, i cant move the camera back anymore since it just goes through the wall and into the other room

Answer (score 0):

just change the focal length of the camera:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for this